# JQuery to add div to text and clear it later

Tags: jquery, html, addition

I have a HTML page in which I have some content that user can search. Here is the example HTML

```
 <span class="name">Red Apple</span>
 <span class="location">Texas</span>
 <span class="date">Mon, Apr 07, 11:15 AM</span>

 <span class="name">California Orange</span>
 <span class="location">California</span>
 <span class="date">Mon, Apr 07, 11:15 AM</span>
```

If the user enters "Apr" and hits search I want to add a div to the two matching span content like this

```
<span class="date">Mon, <div class="red">Apr<div> 07, 11:15 AM</span>
```

Later when the user hits clear search I want to remove these as well.

What is the best way to do this using JQuery?

Comment: you could do that with addClass - removeClass - have a look here http://api.jquery.com/addclass/ - http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/ - no need for adding a div

Comment: does it have to match the whole word or just part of it? this could help (not sure though as work filters are blocking the site) http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/javascript/highlight-words-in-text-with-jquery/

Comment: Where are your users entering this data?

Comment: Have to match part of the text not the whole text. User has a search textbox in which he is entering the search string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use a plugin, you could do this using `replace()`:

```
$('span').html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(searchString, '<div class="red">' + searchString + '</div>');
});
```

Just to note, nesting a `div` within a `span` is not valid. Also, the above example is case sensitive (ie. `red` will not match the word `Red`).

In order to remove the highlighting, you can use `unwrap()`, targeting the `div.red` that has been added:

```
$('div.red').contents().unwrap();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RHWS/14/)

Comment: This works. Thank you! I replaces div with span to since div in span is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try [higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

[Plugin](http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-4.closure.js)

**js**

```js
var hightlight = $('#highlight'),
    txt = $('#txt');
$('#search').click(function () {
    hightlight.highlight(txt.val());
});
$('#clear').click(function () {
    hightlight.removeHighlight();
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="highlight"> <!--  Wrap your searching area in div-->
 <span class="name">Red Apple</span>
 <span class="location">Texas</span>
 <span class="date">Mon, Apr 07, 11:15 AM</span>
 <span class="name">California Orange</span>
 <span class="location">California</span>
 <span class="date">Mon, Apr 07, 11:15 AM</span>

</div>
<input type="text" id="txt" /> <!-- Searching textbox -->
<input type="button" id="search" value="serach" /> <!-- Search on button click-->
<input type="button" id="clear" value="clear" /> <!-- clear highlight on button click-->
```

**CSS**

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: red
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/E233J/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but cannot use plug-ins. Have to do it using JQuery or Javascript. I prefer JQuery.

Comment: If it is for a personal project I would use it but at work we cannot use other JQuery plugins.